# What does "lazy" mean with this code in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, syntax, lazy-evaluation

What is this code line doing?

```
fun<T:x>a.b(y: Int)=lazy{u.v<T>(y)}
```

I do not know what is 'lazy' doing or is 'lazy' something special in Kotlin.

Comment: Search for ["kotlin lazy keyword"](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/lazy.html). The documentation (often found via searching) is a good place to start for such questions.

Comment: @user2864740 I read it, but still can not understand the complete line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> fun<T:x>a.b(y: Int)=lazy{u.v(y)}

Let's break this down. First, let's reformat for readability :)

`fun <T: x> a.b(y: Int) = lazy { u.v<T>(y) }`

Now, let's go piece by piece.

`fun` means we're declaring a new method.

`<T:x>` means this is a generic method operating on type `T` where `T` is [constrained](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#generic-constraints) to be of type `x`.

`a.b` means this is an [extension function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/extensions.html#extensions) named `b` on type `a`.

`(y: Int)` means that the defined function `b` takes a single argument named `y` of type `Int`.

`=` is [expression body syntax](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-syntax.html#defining-functions) - shorthand for returning a short line of code. This means that `a.b` will return the value that is the result of evaluating `lazy { }`

`lazy` is [a Kotlin standard library function](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/lazy.html) that delays the evaluation of the function provided to it until it's needed and then caches the result. The return value of this function is actually a type `Lazy` that wraps the provided function.

`{ u.v<T>(y) }` is the function that will be executed by the `Lazy` object when it's value is obtained the first time and the return value of `u.v<T>(y)` will be saved as the lazy object's `value`.

Phew! So what does that mean? Let's look at an example. Suppose we add a print statement to the function to see when it's called.

```kotlin
fun <T: x> a.b(y: Int) = lazy {
  println("Executing 'b'")
  u.v<T>(y)
}
```

Now if you tried to use it:

```kotlin
fun main() {
  val a = A<T>() // Assume some type T
  val lazyObject = a.b<T>(42) // Call the extension method that returns a `Lazy`
  
  // Get the value from the lazy object - prints "Executing 'b'",
  // executes `u.v<T>(y)`, caches the result, returns it - then print it
  println(lazyObject.value) 
 
  // Get the value from the lazy object again. This time, DOES NOT print
  // "Executing 'b'", DOES NOT execute `u.v<T>(y)`, and just returns the
  // result that was already computed and cached, then print it
  println(lazyObject.value)  
}
```

So, in summary, the code you posted is creating an *extension* method that returns a `Lazy` object that, when queried for its value, executes the lambda it's initialized with and caches that result for later use.

Hope that helps!